# How do I bind the VNC port of a program using qt-embedded to non-localhost?

Tags: qt, embedded

I'm trying to teach a program that uses qt-embedded (sorry no source …) to bind to non-localhost.

The program is started with

```
the_gui -display VNC:size=$size:depth=32:passwordFile=/fubar/vncpassword.txt:0"
```

I have tried multiple ways to tell it to bind to the wildcard IP address, but no luck. How do I do this? Are those options documented anywhere?